# How to find From where a specific stored procedure is called in ASPDotNetStoreFront?

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I am very new to Storefront. I have aspdotnetstorefront code. Can somebody tell me, from where the call to Stored procedure is made?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually at the top of any aspx or xml file

For example at the top of a file to find products you may see something like this

```
<query name="Products" rowElementName="Product">
    <sql>
        <![CDATA[
            exec Product_BestSellers 30, 10, @orderby, @StoreID, @FilterProduct
        ]]>
    </sql>
```

the Stored Procedure used will be the one that is being run. Here it is Product_BestSellers

Comment: Just a clarification: the "xml files" are `XSLT` files and end in `.xml.config`.